# How to create constraint in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create constraint orderDate must be smaller than deliveryDate?
Help me.

Comment: Have u tried anything???? First try by yourself and if u r not getting then ask the question....

Comment: `ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT CK_orderDate_Before_deliveryDate CHECK(orderDate < deliveryDate)`

Answer (score 2):

Supposing the table name is MyTable:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_MyTable_date1] CHECK (orderDate <= deliveryDate)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_MyTable_date1]
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it.

First While creating the table and after the creation:

While creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Price (
PriceID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
OriginalPrice FLOAT NOT NULL,
CurrentPrice FLOAT NOT NULL,
Discount FLOAT,
ShippingCost FLOAT NOT NULL,
Tax FLOAT NOT NULL,
CHECK (CurrentPrice <= OriginalPrice));
```

After creation the table:

```
ALTER TABLE Price ADD CHECK (CurrentPrice <= OriginalPrice);
--or
ALTER TABLE Price ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Price_Current_vs_Original
CHECK (CurrentPrice <= OriginalPrice);
```

You can go for the date fields in the same sense.
For more info please [Read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390490/the-values-of-one-column-cannot-be-greater-than-another)